# Word automation - SaveAs

Tags: c++, com, ms-word

I try to write a simple MFC - Word Automation to save for every 1 minute. 
I follow this article : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/MSOfficeAuto.aspx

And this is what Im trying to implement , I'm new to COM so I think there's problem here:
my VBA is generated by Word 2010:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="1.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument _
    , LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
    WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
     SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
    False, CompatibilityMode:=14
```

And my code to implement VBA code above :

```
{
    COleVariant varName(L"b.docx");
    COleVariant varFormat(L"wdFormatXMLDocument");
    COleVariant varLockCmt((BYTE)0);
    COleVariant varPass(L"");
    COleVariant varReadOnly((BYTE)0);
    COleVariant varEmbedFont((BYTE)0);
    COleVariant varSaveNativePicFormat((BYTE)0);
    COleVariant varForms((BYTE)0);
    COleVariant varAOCE((BYTE)0);
    VARIANT x;
    x.vt = VT_I4;
    x.lVal = 14;
    COleVariant varCompability(&x);;

    VARIANT result;
    VariantInit(&result);
    _hr=OLEMethod(  DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pDocApp, L"SaveAs2",10,
                    varName.Detach(),varFormat.Detach(),varLockCmt.Detach(),varPass.Detach(),varReadOnly.Detach(),
                    varEmbedFont.Detach(),varSaveNativePicFormat.Detach(),varForms.Detach(),varAOCE.Detach(),varCompability.Detach()
                 );
}
```

I get no error from this one, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBA syntax uses named parameters where the order and count of the parameters do not matter. However, when calling from C++ you need to pass the required number of parameters in the right order.

SaveAs2 is defined as:

```
void SaveAs2(
    ref Object FileName,
    ref Object FileFormat,
    ref Object LockComments,
    ref Object Password,
    ref Object AddToRecentFiles,
    ref Object WritePassword,
    ref Object ReadOnlyRecommended,
    ref Object EmbedTrueTypeFonts,
    ref Object SaveNativePictureFormat,
    ref Object SaveFormsData,
    ref Object SaveAsAOCELetter,
    ref Object Encoding,
    ref Object InsertLineBreaks,
    ref Object AllowSubstitutions,
    ref Object LineEnding,
    ref Object AddBiDiMarks,
    ref Object CompatibilityMode
)
```

So, it has 17 parameters which means you should specify them all if you are going to pass CompatibilityMode, which was specified as 10th parameter in your example (that corressponds to SaveFormsData).

If you do not need all the parameters, or just for testing, you can try a simpler code:

```
_hr = OLEMethod(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pDocApp, L"SaveAs2", 2, varName.Detach(), varFormat.Detach());
```

If you need the rest of the parameters, you need to pass all the parameters up to the parameter you need set. In that case, you can pass

```
COleVariant vtOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
```

for the parameters you do not like to set.

**Edit - Test Code**

This works for me:

```
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    CLSID clsid;
    IDispatch *pWApp;
    HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Word.Application", &clsid);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pWApp);

    hr = OLEMethod(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pWApp, L"Visible", 1, COleVariant((long)1));

    VARIANT result;
    VariantInit(&result);
    hr = OLEMethod(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pWApp, L"Documents", 0);
    IDispatch *pDocs = result.pdispVal;

    VARIANT result2;
    VariantInit(&result2);
    hr = OLEMethod(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result2, pDocs, L"Open", 1, COleVariant(L"D:\\Archive\\t1.docx"));
    IDispatch *pDoc = result2.pdispVal;

    VARIANT result3;
    VariantInit(&result3);
    hr = OLEMethod(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result3, pDoc, L"SaveAs2", 1, COleVariant(L"D:\\Archive\\t2.docx"));

    CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the most important thing is "SaveAs2" or "SaveAs" return as Unknown Name

Comment: That means you are sending the wrong interface. Are you sure pDocApp is a Document? I'll update my answer with a test code.

Comment: I found I had to reverse the order of the parameters sent to OLEMethod if there was more than one parameter.  For example: I saved my Word docx as a pdf and used this call to OleMethod:  hr = OleMethod(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result3, pDocs, L"SaveAs2", 2, varFormat,varName); where varFormat is defined as a VT_I4, lVal=17 and varName is a VT_BSTR defined as my fully pathed pdf filename.  varName.bstrVal=::SysAllocString(L"c:\\filename.docx");

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable `varFormat` from `wdFormatXMLDocument` to an integer of `12` (probably like you've done the `varCompability` variable). Also, what's the `10` for after `"SaveAs2"`?

Comment: No it's not :) . It's quite strange , they don't provide any docs about what L"name" I should send.

Comment: You shouldn't have to send any L"name" - just send in the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'll start over since you opened the bounty.

Change your variable varFormat from `wdFormatXMLDocument` to an integer of `12` (probably like you've done the `varCompability` variable). `wdFormatXMLDocument` is an enum of `WdSaveFormat` and was introduced in Word 2003. There is no need to send in an `L"name"` - just send in the integer of `12`.

If these are previously saved documents (i.e. not new ones), perform a conversion first to get it to the right format (like `ActiveDocument.Convert`)

Comment: What version of Word are you referencing? I know you're using `SaveAs2`, but is that the one being automated?